# Why is the experience a character gains different from what is reported at the end of battle?

Tags: persona-5

In **normal mode**, does anyone know why the experience a character actually earns is different from the amount reported at the end of battle?

I've noticed something while playing the game that, for some reason, that the experience reported at the end of a battle is different from what characters in my party receive. For example,

The protagonist is level 22, has 15,674 total experience (with 1,369 to next level). After fighting a group of Shadows comprised of a Jack Frost and two Nue in the second Palace the end results report 182 experience gained from the combat.

Now, if I look at the protagonist's stats I see that he has a 15,841 total experience (with 1,202 to next level).

The difference between before and after is 167 experience, which means somewhere I'm losing 15 experience points for the protagonist.

I'm guessing there is a scale being applied to the *actual* amount of experience each character earns, based on how close in level they are to the enemies fought. It's the only rationale I can think of for the disparity.

Does anyone know for certain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed this, as well. As it turns out, you can actually get more *or* less than what is displayed on the battle result screen. The amount shown is adjusted depending on your level compared to the enemies' level(s). This is explained more in depth in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835628-persona-5/75215999):

> Remember that the number on the screen is a lie. If you're level 8 and kill a level 10 mob, and it says you got 18 XP, you probably got more like 21. If you're level 10 and kill a level 8 mob, and it says you got 14 XP, you probably got more like 10. This allows you to catch up lower-level members and level lower-level personas more reliably. Bottom line, if you're higher level than what you're fighting, stop grinding. The returns are even worse than you think. You can check your stats before and after a battle to test the actual numbers, but yeah. Anti-grinding leveling system in effect.